# My comment form does not appear on the template page (django)

Tags: django

My codes work on local but not work on the net :)

Here is my simple django blog website. When i tested these codes work but when i try live version, it doesnt work. Where is the my fault?

If you wanna see the live page you can look this page https://www.endustri.io/kaynak-perdesi-nedir-ne-ise-yarar-cesitleri-fiyatlari/

I added two types comment section the template page but none of them work.

[image]

My local codes work

[image]

Here is my codes;

blog post codes page (detail.html)

```
{% extends 'blog/base1.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<head>{% block title %}<title>{{ post.title }} - Endustri.io</title>{% endblock %}</head>
<div class="card">
    <h5 class="card-header">{{ post.title }}</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-title">Yazar: {{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }} - Tarih: {{post.date_added}} - Kategori: <a href="{% url 'category' post.category.slug %}"> {{ post.category.title }}</a> <hr/></h6>
      
      <p class="card-text">{{ post.body|safe }}</p>
      
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="card">
    <h5 class="card-header">Yorumlar</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-title">
          {% for comment in comments %}
    <article>
        <strong>{{ comment.name}} at {{ comment.date_added }}</strong></br>
        {{ comment.body }}

    </article>
{% endfor %}</h6>         
    
    </div>
</div>
  
        <form method="POST" class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Yorum Ekle</button>
        </form>
        <br>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Add comment</button>
    </div>
</form>  

{% endblock %}
```

Comment model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'body')
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, slug):
    f = Firma.objects.all()
    kat = Category.objects.all()
    most = Post.objects.order_by('-num_reads')[:10]
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    post.num_reads += 1  
    post.save() 
    
    # Sadece onaylanmış yorumları getir
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.post = post
            obj.save()

            return redirect('detail', slug=post.slug)


    else:    
        form = CommentForm()

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'most': most,
        'kat': kat,
        'comments': comments,

    }  

    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

Comment: You don't pass your form to the view via context variable. Add it in your context variable. This code will not work locally either.

Comment: @Marco you are right. My local codes form is in the context. I added and it fixed. Thanks my friend.